# Displaying multiple objects on map and calculating distances using google api

Tags: javascript, beginner, ajax, async-await, google-maps

I am quite new to Javascript. For a school project we wrote a website that displays the user's location on a google map alongside with some objects such as vehicles or passengers. 
I rewrote my code to include async...await syntax after learning about them. But I still do not know if the code is any good, or if it could be improved. I hoped you guys would have an answer. Here is the code:

```
const myID = 'Wkevc4Sj';
const myIcon = 'images/marker.png';
const passIcon = 'images/passenger.png';
const carIcon = 'images/car.png';
const weinerIcon = 'images/weinermobile.png';
const has = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;

var infowindow = {};
var directionsService = {};
var directionsDisplay = {};
var userLocation = {};
var weinerExists = false;

async function run() {
  try {
    let map = await initMap();
    renderMap(map);
    let userMarker = addUserMarker(map);

    let request = getRide();
    let response = await request;
    let ride = await response.json();
    console.log(ride);
    let userType = has.call(ride, "vehicles") ? "passenger" : "vehicle";

    populateMap(userType, ride, map, userMarker);
  } catch (e)
  {
    alert (e);
  }
}

// getLocation is a promise that resolves with the location that uses navigator
const getLocation = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject);
  } else {
    reject('Browser does not support geolocation');
  }
});

// initMap() when called initializes the map element on the body using
//    the user's location
async function initMap() {
  var position = await getLocation;
  userLocation = {
    lat: position.coords.latitude,
    lng: position.coords.longitude
  };
  return new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: userLocation,
    zoom: 16,
    disableDefaultUI: true
  });
}

// renderMap(map) when given a google.maps.map object,
//    adds direction service and an infoWindow to the map.
//    also adds a marker on the current position of the user.
function renderMap(map) {
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  directionsDisplay.setOptions({
    suppressMarkers: true
  });
}

// getRide() returns a promise that resolves with a JSON object returned from the
//    ride API
async function getRide() {
  const url = 'https://hans-moleman.herokuapp.com/rides';
  const params = `username=${myID}&lat=${userLocation.lat}&lng=${userLocation.lng}`;

  return fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    },
    body: params,
  });
}

// addUserMarker(map) adds a user marker to the provided map
function addUserMarker(map) {
  const content = `<p><strong>Your Location:</strong><br /> Lat = ${precise(userLocation.lat, 4)} Lng = ${precise(userLocation.lng, 4)}`;
  let userMarker = newMarker(userLocation, myIcon, content, map);
  google.maps.event.addListener(userMarker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(this.content);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
  });
  return userMarker;
}

// newMarker(position, icon, content, map) returns a new marker with the
//    arguments as marker properties.
function newMarker(position, icon, content, map) {
  return new google.maps.Marker({
    position: position,
    icon: icon,
    content: content,
    map: map
  });
}

// newMarkerwListener(position, icon, content, map) returns a new marker with
//    arguments as marker properties and a popup click listener added.
function newMarkerwListener(position, icon, content, map) {
  let marker = newMarker(position, icon, content, map);
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(this.content);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
  });

  return marker;
}

// populateMap(userType, ride, map, marker) given the type of the user,
//  ride API response JSON object, a google map and a user marker,
//  populates the map with the objects of the ride and modifies the
//  marker to represent the nearest object
function populateMap(userType, ride, map, marker) {
  const elemArray = ride[userType == "passenger" ? "vehicles" : "passengers"];
  let nearest = elemArray[0];
  let weinerMobile = {};

  for (var i = 0; i < elemArray.length; i++) {
    let elem = elemArray[i];
    let nearestDistance = distanceTo(userLocation, nearest);
    let distance = distanceTo(userLocation, elem);

    let content = `<p><strong>Name: </strong> ${elem.username}<br />${distance} miles away from you`;
    let icon = userType == "vehicle" ? passIcon : carIcon;

    if (elem.username == "WEINERMOBILE") {
      icon = weinerIcon;
      weinerExists = true;
      weinerMobile = elem;
    }
    newMarkerwListener(elem, icon, content, map);
    nearest = nearestDistance < distance ? nearest : elem;
  }

  if (!(nearest === undefined)) {
    marker.content += `<br /><strong>Nearest: ${nearest.username}</strong><br />${distanceTo(userLocation, nearest)} miles away from you`;
  }

  if (weinerExists) {
    marker.content += `<br /><strong>Weinermobile:</strong><br />${distanceTo(userLocation, weinerMobile)} miles away`;
  } else {
    marker.content += "<br />The Weinermobile is nowhere to be seen";
  }

}

/* HELPER FUNCTIONS */
function precise(x, y) {
  return Number.parseFloat(x).toPrecision(y);
}

function findDistFromTo(from, to) {
  var vLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(
    parseFloat(from.lat),
    parseFloat(from.lng)
  );
  var cLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(
    parseFloat(to.lat),
    parseFloat(to.lng)
  );
  return google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(
    cLatLng,
    vLatLng
  );
}

function toMiles(meters) {
  return meters * 0.000621371192;
}

function distanceTo(from, to) {
  return precise(toMiles(findDistFromTo(from, to)), 4);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

My observations:

1. Use `let` instead of `var`. You are already using `let` in some places, but a few need to be converted. For those that do not know the difference, [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) is one of the new features in ES2015 (ES6) and it respects block scopes in the same way as other programming languages.
2. ~~
3. I would use file scope constants for the strings "passenger" and "vehicle". Makes it easier in the future to do refactors. For example, at the top of the file `const PASSENGER = 'passenger'`
4. Change this `if (!(nearest === undefined))` to `if (!!nearest)`, what you care about is if its a truthy value. The specificity of "not undefined" would allow other falsy values like `0`, `null`, `NaN`, `''`, `""`, ````
5. If file scope constant were to be used and all the possible values are known, you could test for those specifically. Instead of `if (!!nearest)` you could `if ([PASSENGER, VEHICLE].includes(nearest))`